# Wordpress title is not displayed correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created a new page in Wordpress and the title of this new page does not look like the other page titles. For all other pages there is a picture in the background, the text is displayed in a white color etc. as seen in the screenshot below.

I have not built the other pages, therefore i do not know how to solve the issue.

I am really thankful for your help!

[How the title of the new created page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pBN.png)

[How titles from other pages look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7oBS.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then read [ask] here. After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [mre] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just post a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score -1):

Is your website built on a theme, if so you may have not selected the correct page template. Its usually in the right side menu when editing the page.

If your using another builder such as Elementor or WP Bakery then it maybe slightly different?